# IDE не выводит методы подключенных библиотек

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm, ide, webstorm

Подскажите как настроить, чтобы webStorm при разработке для NodeJS, выводил методы подключаемых библиотек. Сейчас он не делает этого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для `bcrypt-nodejs` у меня все выводится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несколько советов, которые помогают почти всегда:

- попробуйте скачать TypeScript stubs для вашего модуля. сделать это можно прямо из редактора: наведите курсор на имя модуля и нажмите `Alt+Enter`, из выпадающего меню выберите `Install typescript definitions for better type information`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- еще я бы посоветовала подключить библиотеку **Node.js Core**, чтобы ресолвились базовые методы вроде `require()`. Сделать это можно в **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**